# Simple storage engines or low-level databases embeddable in Java

Tags: java, database

I'd like to find simple storage engines or low-level databases, embeddable in Java. I.e. libraries.

They only have to be able to store bytes, really. Keys could be simply integers.

No querying required. I am investigating the idea of dealing with persistence or even implementing databases on top of such a simple foundation.

Of course, fast, lean, simple are good qualities.

(Wasn't able to use (create) additional tags: low-level, storage)

Comment: Java on what OS?

Comment: @rrirower I am thinking pure JVM code, so OS shouldn't matter too much. Of course, there may be small differences in things like memory-mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a pure Java lib you can look on [HeftyDB](https://github.com/jordw/heftydb). If you are ok with native lib and Java wrappers there are many options:

- [LMDB](http://symas.com/mdb/)
- [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb)
- [RocksDB](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/tree/master/java)

Answer (score 2):

## H2 Database, MVStore

The pure-Java relational database engine, [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/), has an explicit key-value store called [*MVStore*](http://www.h2database.com/html/mvstore.html).

> Each store contains a number of maps that can be accessed using the java.util.Map interface.
>
> Both file-based persistence and in-memory operation are supported.
>
> It is intended to be fast, simple to use, and small.
>
> Concurrent read and write operations are supported.
>
> Transactions are supported (including concurrent transactions and 2-phase commit).

Can even be used directly, without using JDBC or SQL.

Example code:

```
// open the store
MVStore s = MVStore.open( fileName );

// create/get the map named "data"
MVMap<Integer, String> map = s.openMap( "data" );

// add and read some data
map.put( 1, "Hello World" );
System.out.println( map.get(1) );

// close the store (this will persist changes)
s.close();
```

Comment: Checked it out a little. Log-structured storage, I like that. Can store Java arrays, so my requirement is met. Seems a little higher-level than I was aiming for, though; it can store many more data types. Cool feature: 'The MVRTreeMap is an R-tree implementation that supports fast spatial queries.'